# Cannot find "Paste Special" option in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I cannot see the `Paste Special` option in my Visual Studio 2017 Professional Edition:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017
>
> Version 15.4.5
>
> VisualStudio.15.Release/15.4.5+27004.2010
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework
>
> Version 4.7.02046

In [this blog post](https://blog.codeinside.eu/2014/09/08/Visual-Studio-2013-Paste-Special-JSON-And-Xml/) it is shown for Visual Studio 2013. On my machine, the edit menu appears as below:

[image]

Is there a way to get back the option? Do I need to enable this option somehow?

Comment: Works on my machine.  But I've avoided keeping it updated, life's too short.  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem.  Beware that you'll have to provide better repro steps than you did here or they'll ignore it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have missed an important step. There is nothing wrong in Visual Studio 2017. I was not in a .cs file.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer to this problem is the WCF component is not installed in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The `Paste Special` option will not show if you are debugging.

I stopped my application and the `Paste Special` option appeared right away.

This was in Visual Studio 2017, but I assume it would be the same for all versions.