# NewtonSoft Deserialize Same Object from multiple sources with different property names

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

Imagine having the following class

```
public class Person
{
public int Id {get; set;}
[JsonProperty("first_name")]
public string FirstName {get; set;}
[JsonProperty("last_name")]
public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

I have two sources of JSON that I'm currently using to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(source)`. This puts me in a pickle. Both sources must have identical property names in order for this to work. For the sake of this exercise, let's assume the followings for `source`.

source 1:

```
{
"id" : 1,
"first_name": "Jon",
"last_name": "Doe"
}
```

source 2:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "firstName": "Jon",
    "lastName": "Doe"
}
```

In this scenario, the second source isn't going to get deserialized into the `Person` object because the property names don't match.

I'm not sure how to deserialize these two sources to the same object without having the need to create a new object, which I don't want to do.

Comment: Option #1) Create separate intermediate objects to deserialize the two JSON versions into, then map those objects to your Person. Option #2) Create a custom converter for the JSON, [Custom JSON Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67222008/deserializing-a-json-array-with-awkward-additional-property-in-the-schema)

Comment: Deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, object>` and then populate the object from that. No matter what, you're going to need to have another set of mappings between JSON property name and C# property name. Pick your poison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this using a custom `JsonConverter`...

Implement a custom `JsonConverter` that defines the field name mappings that can be different ...

```
public class PersonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> propertyMappings { get; set; }

    public PersonConverter()
    {
        this.propertyMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"firstName","first_name"},
            {"lastName","last_name"},
        };
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
        var props = objectType.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties.ToList();

        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        foreach (JProperty jp in jo.Properties())
        {
            if (!propertyMappings.TryGetValue(jp.Name, out var name))
                    name = jp.Name;

            PropertyInfo prop = props.FirstOrDefault(pi =>
                    pi.CanWrite && pi.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>().PropertyName == name);

            prop?.SetValue(instance, jp.Value.ToObject(prop.PropertyType, serializer));
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.GetTypeInfo().IsClass;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;
}
```

Add the `JsonConverter` attribute on your object class, so your custom converter is used during deserializtion...

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(PersonConverter))]
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

To use the custom converter...

```
string json_first_name = "{\"id\" : 1,\"first_name\": \"Jon\",\"last_name\": \"Doe\"}";
string json_firstname = "{\"id\" : 1,\"firstName\": \"Jon\",\"lastName\": \"Doe\"}";

var objFirst_Name = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json_first_name);
var objFirstName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json_firstname);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create some setter only proxy properties (which you just ignore everywhere else, as the naming implies):

```
public class Person
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  [JsonProperty("firstName")]
  public string FirstName {get; set;}
  [JsonProperty("lastName")]
  public string LastName {get; set;}
    
  [JsonProperty("first_name")]
  public string __Ignore1 { set { FirstName = value; } }
  [JsonProperty("last_name")]
  public string __Ignore2 { set { LastName = value; } }
}
```

Fiddle demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/chS5fW).

I tried using NamingStrategy, but seems that only can tweak things the other way.  I see no harm in this little hack - by being set only, they don't serialize.

Comment: That's a nice trick! But it makes the class ugly and might not make it through the Code review.

Comment: For sure, pick your poison.  Definitely depends on the project, team, codebase, etc.  For example, if this is just for a little console app or service parsing this one thing - it's totally acceptable for anyone on my team to code this efficiently like this..  However, if this is part of a large application that needs to do this to many types in a similar pattern - your generic approach should be used (although I'd make more generic - stripping symbols and lowercasing).

Answer (score 1):

You do not necessarily need to create a new mapping. There are probably many ways to do it, a clever hack is the one proposed by @TheSoftwareJedi, here is another solution:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    //[JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    //[JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}

private static void PrintDeserializedObject(string obj, DefaultContractResolver resolver) 
{
    var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = resolver,
        
    });
    Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}.{2}", person.Id, person.FirstName, person.LastName);
}

public static void Main()
{
    var firstObj = @"{
        ""id"" : 1,
        ""first_name"": ""Jon"",
        ""last_name"": ""Doe""
        }";
    
    var secondObj = @"{
        ""id"" : 1,
        ""firstName"": ""Jon"",
        ""lastName"": ""Doe""
        }"; 
    
    DefaultContractResolver snakeResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
    };

    PrintDeserializedObject(firstObj, snakeResolver);
    PrintDeserializedObject(secondObj, new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
}
```

The idea is to use a `ContractResolver` and the `NamingStrategy`. As for the camel case, there is a built-in [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm). Instead, for the snake case, you have to create a new `DefaultContractResolver` with the naming strategy set to [`SnakeCaseNamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_SnakeCaseNamingStrategy.htm).

Note that in this case, you may get rid of `JsonPropertyAttribute`s, at least I have not found a way to override them from the `JsonSerializerSettings`.

[Try the fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yAi3WL)